# Publishing requirement for Internal Test Track - Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

Somehow I am not able to fathom as to why there is a requirement of publishing for even **INTERNAL TEST TRACK**. Obviously, I am talking about the first apk push on play store.

It is understandable that Google needs to protect its reputation and end users from bad/worse/evil apps. But, as I understand, the internal test track is only available for internal testing where a set of identified people can only test the app. And the app can be released only from Alpha/Beta tracks.

The issue is that these days the review time is enormous , like , 1 week and even more. So, I basically have to wait 1 week to even start testing. Consider if I have already reviewed myself and then uploaded on internal test track, it just means that I am doing nothing other than waiting for this review.

Is it just me blabbering or others have faced time issue too ?

Or, Am I doing something wrong !. Is there a way to make it faster.
Do keep in mind that it is my first android app.

Comment: I had the same issue. All I wanted to do was test the APK on our internal test track but had to wait a week for Google to approve it. It doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

For the first APK you should wait a lot of time... During this period also due to coronavirus (COVID-19). You should wait the reponse from Google...